# RegOpenKeyEx returns bad path name error (code 161)

Tags: c#, windows, .net-3.5, registry

I'm using [this solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/5f832b8f-979d-4a66-a4c8-5d4c18eb9f35) to read 32-bit registry on a 64-bit machine. I'm using it like this:

```
GetKeyValue("\\software\\company", name);
```

where `name` is the name of the retrieved property. But the code returns the 161 code. I also tried appending the backslash at the end of the path, but the result is the same. I can confirm that the key exist there in regedit. What's wrong?

Comment: Have you used the KEY_WOW64_32KEY flag?

Comment: @ken2k: Yep, it's in the code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be a backslash at the beginning of the path (or at the end).  This should work:

```
GetKeyValue("SOFTWARE\\company", name);
```